# How do you define backdoor access for fields which span two registers?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have a register map which has 16 bit wide registers.  I have a field with is greater than 16 bits wide, so it must span two addresses.  How do I define the backdoor access to this field?

This is what I tried for my field `test_pattern[23:0]`:

```
register_a.add_hdl_path_slice("path.to.regmap.test_pattern[15:0]", 0, 16);
register_b.add_hdl_path_slice("path.to.regmap.test_pattern[23:16]", 0, 8);
```

This fails with this error:

> ERROR:          VPI       TYPERR
>            vpi_handle_by_name() cannot get a handle to a part select.

It is not clear if this is a constraint of my tool, or of how the UVM code uses the VPI.  After poking around inside the UVM code I see the code that should handle part-selects, but it is inside `#ifdef QUESTA` directives so I think this is a tool constraint.

Is there a good work around for this?

Comment: You might want to make the UVM developers aware of this issue: http://forums.accellera.org/topic/1725-uvm-12-feedback-required/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [UVM Class Reference](http://www.accellera.org/downloads/standards/uvm):

> ```
> function void add_hdl_path_slice(string name,
>     int offset,
>     int size,
>     bit first = 0,
>     string kind = "RTL")
> ```

I'm guessing the solution should use the `offset` to select the starting index.

```
register_a.add_hdl_path_slice("path.to.regmap.test_pattern", 0, 16);
register_b.add_hdl_path_slice("path.to.regmap.test_pattern", 16, 8);
```

---

Possible alternative, bit select in a for-loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<16; i++) begin
  string tmp_path_s;
  tmp_path_s = $sformatf("path.to.regmap.test_pattern[%0d]", i);
  register_a.add_hdl_path_slice(tmp_path_s, i, 1);
end
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) begin
  string tmp_path_s;
  tmp_path_s = $sformatf("path.to.regmap.test_pattern[%0d]", i+16);
  register_a.add_hdl_path_slice(tmp_path_s, i, 1);
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that offset refers to the offset in the register not the field.

Answer (score 0):

It's a great pity that whoever contributed this code (presumably Mentor?) felt it necessary to add a useful feature to a *Universal* library wrapped in `ifdefs`. In fact it's even worse on the `UVM_1_2` branch where the whole DPI/PLI interface file is split into simulator specific implementations!

Looking at `distrib/src/dpi/uvm_hdl.c` on master branch of git://git.code.sf.net/p/uvm/code it looks like the only QUESTA specific code is this function:

```
static int uvm_hdl_set_vlog_partsel(char *path, p_vpi_vecval value, PLI_INT32 flag);
static int uvm_hdl_get_vlog_partsel(char *path, p_vpi_vecval value, PLI_INT32 flag);
```

Which uses the following DPI defined values:

```
svLogic logic_bit;
svGetBitselLogic(&bit_value,0);
svLogicVecVal bit_value;
svGetPartselLogic(&bit_value,value,i,1);
svPutPartselLogic(value,bit_value,i,1);
```

In theory if both your simulator and the Mentor code are compliant to the standard you could remove the `ifdefs` and it *should* still work.

You could also do this by detecting the part select in the path and use `vpi_handle_by_index` to read the individual bits, which should also be supported in any simulator.

NB my original answer was wrong about the code being Mentor specific - thanks to @dave_59 for setting me straight and apologies to Mentor.

Comment: These are all defined in the DPI section of the IEEE 1800-2012 LRM and much more efficient than using the PLI. Make sure you are pointing your finger in the right direction.

Comment: @dave_59 fair point about DPI - however my main point still stands - adding functionality (that isn't just a simulator specific workaround) wrapped in `ifdef MY_SIMULATOR` is _not_ a good way to build UVM, and it's only got worse in UVM 1.2.  If it conforms to the standard why the `ifdef`? Also why is PLI used at all if DPI is more efficient?

Comment: @dave_59 Apologies, and thanks for pointing out my mistake. I've now updated my answer.  Since you're involved in the UVM committee is it possible to suggest that other simulator vendors implement the same feature (presumably by copy'n'pasting the code into their files) - or better yet revert back to a common implementation so that copy'n'paste isn't required?

Comment: The whole point of this package is that SystemVerilog does not have the introspection required to look up a variable by a string name. Neither does the DPI. So you need the PLI/VPI to lookup the object. However, the PLI was design to be incredibly safe which makes it incredibly slow. The DPI gives you C-style pointer access to your SV variables making it faster, but much easier to corrupt the simulation by mistake.

Comment: In a perfect world, ANY_VENDOR would interpret the Verilog/SystemVerilog LRM perfectly the same as ANY_VENDOR. But that has never been the case even for constructs dating back to when Verilog first became an open standard in 1990. Since there is no compliance testing body, we don't always catch these differences until a user of both vendors reports it. By that time, even if the standard is clarified, there are too many individual users of each vendor tools that would be impacted to change the software, so users of both tools need to put in the `ifdefs.

Comment: @dave_59 I understand why this C file is required.  My questions are: (1) Since DPI/PLI are standard, why is this useful feature in `#ifdef QUESTA` tags?;  (2) Why is the package split out into 3 different implementations in `UVM_1_2` branch;  (3) Are you able / willing to help rectify this situation (since you are involved in the standard)? Or perhaps you don't see any of these things as an issue?

Comment: @dave_59 sorry our comments collided.  I acknowledge that `#ifdef VENDOR` will always be required due to slight quirks between vendors, but this is a whole new feature not a vendor specific workaround.  Splitting out into completely separate files is a step backwards, surely the standards are standard enough to have a common base implementation with a few `ifdef`s where required?

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason why you aren't splitting this into 2 registers. Since your register size is 16 bits it doesn't make sense to declare a register that is larger than this.

The way I've seen large fields like this defined is to declare 2 registers with a separate field in each. For example, if you needed a 32-bit pointer you'd have:

addr_high with a 16 bit field
addr_low with a 16 bit field

For convenience, you could add a task that would access both in sequence.

Comment: Internally this is a 24 bit bus which drives some logic.  It's basically ugly to have to split that up into pieces just because the register width is 16 bits.  I can glue these two pieces back together with a concatenation but there is no technical reason why the bus can't span two addresses.  The tool we use to generate our register RTL supports large bit fields spanning multiple addresses so the only reason not to do it is because of this UVM limitation.

Comment: Have you tried declaring this register to have a width of 24 bits? I don't have the uvm reference in front of me, but I thought the register width was an attribute of uvm_reg, not uvm_block. So I think you should be able to have registers with different widths. Then you wouldn't need to add a slice, you could just pass the hdl path directly in uvm_reg::configure.

Comment: That would work, but the SPI interface does work on 16 bit boundaries so one address can only map to 16 bits.  Either way, my Cadence AE has put this in as an enhancement request but I have not yet had a chance to see if it works. As you can see from the comments above Mentor already supports the feature.  Not sure about Synopsys.

Comment: I thnk that it would still work, it's just that there would be one 16-bit address that wouldn't be mapped to a register because the 32-bit register is using it.